# DRF Serializer is returning empty dictionary while doing serializer.data

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer like following:

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, write_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, write_only=True)

    def validate(self, validate_data):
        username = validate_data.get('username', None)
        password = validate_data.get('password', None)
        if username is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'error': 'Email is required!'})
        if password is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'error': 'Password is required!'})
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return {'username': user.username, 'token': 'token'}
```

and a view for this:

```
class LoginAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(serializer.data) # this prints {}
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'error': serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I don't know what is wrong here, do I have to return validate_data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use create method:

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # required=True to prevent hard-code validation
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, write_only=True, required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, write_only=True, required=True)  

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return {'username': user.username, 'token': 'token'}
```

And this will be your post method:

```
class LoginAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            data = serializer.save()  # call save to create token
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'error': serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: No, It still returns nothing with serializer.data but works with data = serializer.save(). Why? Also why it will not work with validate method?

Comment: @FightWithCode validate method is exists for validation data, not for creation, not for representation. if you still want to use `serializer.data` then you have to check how property data works and after that override `to_representation` method

Comment: @FightWithCode https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/